# Having problems with VBA. Run time error '91' appears to me. Any idea?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to unzip a file using VBA but get the run time error 91. This is my code:

```
Dim Destino As String
Dim Origen As String
Dim oAplica As Object

Destino = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads"
Origen = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\PD20210822.zip"
Set oAplica = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oAplica.Namespace(Destino).CopyHere oAplica.Namespace(Origen).Items
```

Comment: Try `oAplica.Namespace((Destino)).CopyHere oAplica.Namespace((Origen)).Items`

Answer (score 8):

Change `Destino = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads` to `Destino = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\"`. Also change declaration as `String` to `Variant`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim Destino As Variant
Dim Origen As Variant
Dim oAplica As Object

Destino = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\"
Origen = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\PD20210822.zip"
Set oAplica = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oAplica.Namespace(Destino).CopyHere oAplica.Namespace(Origen).Items
```

**Explanation**: You are using **Late Binding**. To understand this, use **Early Binding** as shown below. Set a reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` from `Tools | References`

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Destino As Variant
    Dim Origen As Variant
    Dim oAplica As Shell32.Shell

    Destino = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\"
    Origen = "C:\Users\Oscar Mayorga\Downloads\PD20210822.zip"
    Set oAplica = New Shell32.Shell
    oAplica.Namespace(Destino).CopyHere oAplica.Namespace(Origen).Items
End Sub
```

Now when you press spacebar after you type the **bracket**, you will notice the below

[image]

It expects a `Variant`. More about it can be read in [Shell.NameSpace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

In case the above link dies

[image]